# Software for audio processing: improving intelligibility

Tags: audio, audio-editing

Besides Audacity, what software are there for audio enhancement? Basically, I'm interested in speech audio. Cleaning of background noise can be done really well with Audacity, but what else can be done to improve speech understanding, or to establish the identity of the speakers? Or maybe for getting an insight into age or gender of speaker (more in the sense of forensics)?

I can be for Linux, iOS or Windows, commercial or open source.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide your OS and price requirements. If you want paid solution and OS is Windows here are two alternatives for Audacity.

**Option 1:** Adobe Audition

> Edit, mix, record, and restore audio.
>
> Audition CC is a comprehensive toolset that includes multitrack,
>   waveform, and spectral display for creating, mixing, editing, and
>   restoring audio content. This powerful audio workstation is designed
>   to accelerate video production workflows and audio finishing — and
>   deliver a polished mix with pristine sound.

Source: adobe.com

[Adobe Audition web page](https://www.adobe.com/products/audition.html)

[image: Adobe Audition screenshot]

**Option 2:** Sound Forge

> Free, high-quality solution for music and audio editing.
>
> Start recording with a click using the redesigned recording dialog.
>   Select between threshold, MTC or timestamp recording via the recording
>   options. Record on up to 32 tracks simultaneously and in
>   ultra-high-resolution audio in 64-bit/192 kHz.
>
> Sound design
>
> Includes an impressive range of editing functions for advanced
>   editing: convert regions to events, lock event markers, region
>   markers, and envelope points to events, and automatically ripple
>   successive events forward in time while editing.
>
> Audio editing
>
> Plug-ins from specialists such as iZotope® and zplane. SpectraLayers
>   Pro now seamlessly integrated for comprehensive spectral editing.
>   Everything you need in one fully customizable user interface.
>
> Post production
>
> Master your audio and video projects with effects from iZotope®.
>   Create DAO CD masterings to Red Book specification. Or export
>   multichannel files in surround AC-3 format using the included Dolby
>   Digital AC-3 plug-in.

Source: magix.com

[More information about Sound Forge](https://www.magix.com/int/free-download/sound-forge-pro/)

[image: Sound Forge screenshot]

**Edit:** If you need more professional software you could try Cubase.

Comment: I updated the question, but these tips seem to be on the money.

Comment: That's right. I thought KWave could do your job but it's far behind from Audacity I guess.